# scrolling text in a bar

Tags: java, text, scroll

I'm making a program in java that recive some strings and then display them in a new frame scolling them in one line, like the news, (shown below)

[image]

There, the text are displayed in a line, like what I need, but my problem is that I don't know what I should use in java, I though about put a panel on a frame and then a textfield inside the panel, then I realize that it's impossible because for every message I may need to change the color of background for an highlight message...
So, if anyone can help me, can you tell me what should i use for the diferent message and how i can get the text scrolling?
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: What layout you are using?

Comment: I was using free layout but that isnt the problem, I need something that can move text and for every message let me change the background and color text if I need to...

Comment: you want to change background color or every message, like one message red other blue, or just one red for all is fine?

Comment: I took that image from google but I wanted to do like that white bar but if there is an important message, this must be highlighted by changing the text color and the background of that message to yellow or red...